# Hide all li elements matching string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a list that I want to hide all li elements containing a certain text. Lets say it looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

So how can I hide all li elements containing "historical"? the list is dynamical and will change over time.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ & http://api.jquery.com/remove

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal $("li:contains('historical')").hide();
        var ch = $(".chosen-drop").children;
        for (var i = 0; ch < length; i++) {
            if (ch[i].indexOf('historical') >= 0) {
                ch[i].remove();
            };

        }

Comment: `$("li:contains('historical')").hide();` did not work ?

Comment: @MihaiT I have tried that already did not work tho

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpkov9su/ seems to work

Comment: Here's a simple solution which you can paste in the console right here on this page to remove all _text_ from your `li` elements. Make changes yourself to remove what you want. 
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a).map(name => a[name]).filter(elem => elem.innerHTML == 'text').forEach(elem => elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this selector:** `li:contains('historical')`

## Look at this code snippet

*One line of code.*

```js
$("#target > li:contains('historical')").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='target'>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

See? the `li` elements were hidden.

Comment: Yes I have tried that already but it dont work in my case and I dont know why

Comment: @Patte very weird, that's the cleanest way to accomplish your scenario.  Good luck!

Comment: Now i just feel dumb the list was getting items every time it was clicked (I didn't do that) and i didn't even see it beacuse there is so much files. But I managed to get it working on server side code instead. thanjks for the help tho :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression to filter the historical li's...

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(lis,function(li){
  if(li.textContent.match(/historical/g)){
    li.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with **jQuery**'s `each()`:

```js
$('ul > li').each(function(){
  if($(this).text().includes('historical'))
    $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: `remove` !== `hide`.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It works in this example dont work at all in mine. Cant share my code tho so i guess i will have to keep on trying

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). In the snippet there's an example with [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
var text = 'text historical';

$('ul li:contains('+text+')').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

But you can [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) without [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
var text = 'text historical';

$('ul li:contains('+text+')').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

The only problem is, that in this case, if you use the `text var` as "text", it will hide "text historical" too, as it contains "text":

```js
var text = 'text';

$('ul li:contains('+text+')').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

You have another way, using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and verifying if the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) inside of the element is equal to your `var`:

```js
var text = 'text';

$('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() === text){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) too:

```js
var text = 'text';

$('ul li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text historical</li>    
</ul>
```